# removing index.php in hmvc

Tags: codeigniter, url, codeigniter-hmvc

i want to removing index.php in hmvc code igniter , when i type the url without index.php it's running well but when i process to other controller the url is automatically showing index.php after my codeigniter folder.

example i type :

```
localhost/ci_hmvc/user/login
```

and the result when i process to other controller is :

```
localhost/ci_hmvc/index.php/user/dashboard
```

and my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci_hmvc/index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

please any one help me

Comment: is there a redirect on login.php controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make changes in `config.php` which is in config folder
You can see the line

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

Change this line in to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

I hope this will helps you

Comment: and also check what you have in base_url

Answer (score 0):

put this code in .htaccess and place the htaccess file to the root of the folder..

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ ./index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```